# Why does my actorFor fail when deployed to a Akka Microkernel JAR?

Tags: scala, akka

Have a somewhat simple project deployed to a JAR. I am starting up a supervisor actor that confirms it is booting up by sending out the following log message:

`[akka://service-kernel/user/Tracker] Starting new Tracker`

However, when I go to reference the actor via `actorFor` locally with an `sbt run`, it finds it no problem. In production, I use the same `.actorFor("akka://service-kernel/user/Tracker")` and it throws a `NullPointerException`. I can confirm via the logs that in production, the `Tracker` has sent out its confirmation that it booted up.

Are there any issues when using a Microkernel deployed to a JAR to make actor references?

### Edit

I am suspecting that both the way I reference the system and the way Akka treats the start up class are related to the issue. Since I have specified a start up class called `ServiceKernel`, I am performing the reference as such: `ServiceKernel.system.actorFor`. Will provide an answer if confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that it was related to the startup class handling the Microkernel.

The `ServiceKernel` mentioned above is used in the start script to boot up the Microkernel JAR: `./start com.package.ServiceKernel`. In an sbt shell, this isn't needed so the alternative class I provided works well for referencing an Actor System.

However, in a Microkernel the `ServiceKernel` appears to be using a different Actor System altogether, so if you reference that system (like I did) then `actorFor` lookups will always fail. I solved the problem by passing the system down into the boot classes into the specific class where I was making the `actorFor` reference and it worked. Did it like this (pseudo-code):

```
class ServiceKernel extends Bootable {

  val system = ActorSystem("service-kernel")

  def startup = {
    system.actorOf(Props(new Boot(isDev, system))) ! Start
  }

}
```

And then passing it to an `HttpApi` class:

```
class Boot(val isDev: Boolean, system: ActorSystem) extends Actor with SprayCanHttpServerApp {

  def receive = {
    case Start =>
          // setup HTTP server
          val service = system.actorOf(Props(new HttpApi(system)), "tracker-http-api")
  }
}
```